# Security issues regarding a configuration xml file

Tags: java, android

In my application I have a `config.xml` file which is being parsed,. In this configuration file, there is some data that I don't what the end-user to see in plaintext. In this particular case, a password for a mail account. The `config.xml` file is saved to a folder with the path

```
/mnt/sdcard/my_application_folder/config.xml
```

I have looked up some methods which is provided by the class `File`

- setReadable(boolean value)
- setExecutable(boolean value)
- setWritable(boolean value)

I tried to apply these methods this way:

```
String path = folder.getPathToNode() + "/config.xml";
configFile = new File(path);

if(configFile.exists()) {
    configFile.setReadable(false);
    configFile.setExecutable(true);
    configFile.setWritable(false);
}
```

I guess that some of you would suggest that I store this data in `SharedPreferences`, but my application has two user groups, the **end-user** and an **administrator** which will edit the `config.xml` on his computer, and transfer the file over to the phone.

I can open `Astro File Manager` and see the `config.xml` in plain text, but I should not because the file is not readable?

Can I parse this `config.xml` if I apply the values above? Can anybody suggest another solution to this "security issue"?

Comment: Please see any of the numerous discussions on SO about securing data on Android.  Short story is you can't, and if you're considering storing a password (which I assume is not the users') on the device, I recommend rethinking your approach.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't save sensitive data on the SD card/external storage. Any application can read it, even without special permissions. Find another way to update settings (via the UI, server push, etc.) or at least think of some way to encrypt or obfuscate sensitive information. External storage is generally VFAT (or emulates it), so you cannot set file permissions.

Answer (score 0):

In addition to Nikolay, storing a password in plain text is never a good idea. I'm not an android expert, but I'm sure they provide api's to [en/de]crypt data.